# Is SQLAlchemy ORM the right choice for larga data?

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web application where at some point, I need to select 1.000.000 rows from my database.

My script looks like this :

```
engine = create_engine(
             "mysql://:@localhost/test",
             isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED",echo=False
        )

meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(bind=engine)


cr =  meta.tables['cr']
bl = meta.tables['bl']

DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autoflush=True,
       autocommit=False,
         bind=engine
    )
)

test_query = session.query(bl,cr).filter(bl.c.severity_logged == '4_minor')
print test_query.all()
```

It keeps scanning the disc and increasing the memory usage but doesn't show anything.

In MySQL command, the result is returned in 4 seconds.
How can I use SQLALchemy to retrieve large amounts of data?

Comment: First, are you sure that the query you are generating from SQLAlchemy and the query that you putting in MySQL are the same? Second, do you REALLY need to get 1M rows at once?

Comment: Yes i am sure that both queries are the same.   
Well what I need to do is, get the 1 000 000 query rows results, store them in a list of dicts (Python) then calculate some metrics on the results. Maybe I don't need to store the query results into memory in order to later do the calculations on them? What do you suggest, i'm a newbie in Python so your help would be great.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SQLAlchemy, but maybe it's worthwhile checking if you can get SQL to calculate the "metrics" for you via an aggregate function, instead of calculating it yourself. Then you would'nt need to retrieve one million rows... This obviously depends on the complexity of what you'd want to calculate...

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using SQLAlchemy you are asking it to create 1,000,000+ instances of data-access objects for `bl` and `cr`.  This will be slow, no matter what language or construct you do this in.  You'll be better off either:

- Filtering the data down to a reasonable amount to show on a screen (e. g. `test_query.limit(100).all()`) *or*
- Skipping the DAO step completely and just streaming the data to its endpoint (in this case standard out).

Comment: what is DAO? I didn't understand your second solution

Comment: @user1734229- **D** ata **A** ccess **O** bject.  In this second case you would just create a connection off your `engine` and then `cursor = conn.execute("SQL HERE")` and then `print cursor.fetchall()`.